# accounting for the case that several directories in a path do not exist

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I have a small python app which has optional arguments that output CSVs. In the optional arguments, you can specify a directory in which it will save.
However, the problem which I am facing is if someone specifies several paths in sequence that do not exist.

Imagine the file structure is like so:

```
var/
  csv/
etc/
  sql/
app/
  front_end/
    templates/
  back_end/
    app.py*
```

Now they go in and try to run this argument:

```
$Crow: app.py --save_path='../../csv/saved_csvs/long_path_name/ --name=saved
```

Given none of these directories exist, how could you recursively create them for the following final result?

```
var/
  csv/
etc/
  sql/
csv/
  saved_csvs/
    long_path_name/
      saved.csv
app/
  front_end/
    templates/
  back_end/
    app.py*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.makedirs` to recursively create the leaf directories. It will throw an exception if a leaf exists, but create parent directories as needed.